# How can I style the Comment Section of a blog post

Tags: customization, css, comments, blog

I am trying finish styling this page.  Once someone posts a comment, it looks like this (see below).  I am trying to get the background area just plain black, just like the actual blog text.  Then the actual text to be white. The leave a reply section is fine to be white, as you can still see what is being typed.  I am not sure exactly how to do that.  I have been playing around with theme options, but can't seem to find anything.  Anyone willing to help me out.  Im sure I can add come custom css code, but not sure how to do that.  Thanks in advance.

Heres the page :  https://sterling-dev.com/?p=101

Answer (score 0):

Open your CSS editor by going to `Appearance => Customize => Additionall CSS`

Next, add the CSS there and save it. The live editor will show you results in real-time.

```
.comment {
    background: none;
}
```

Use any of the either. The first one is better. It will cope with the color of your blog-content if you change the blog-content background.

```
.comment {
   background: #111111;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your repose.  Unfortunately, the code you provided just changed my reply comment background to black, or none.  Which still helped, and let me in the right direction.  I found the correct tag to achieve my desired results.                                    .comment.depth-1.parent{
 background: none;
}